# RecyclerView is null android studio

Tags: android, webservice, recyclerview, null

Lo que quiero hacer es:

a la hora de dar click en en cualquier tab, obtener el texto del tab y realizar una consulta a la base de datos con ese texto y mostrar productos de ese texto.

ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este código funciona perfectamente sin la base de datos, pero cuando quiero ejecutar la funcion a la base de datos me marca error en el recyclerview, obviamente hay otras clases, pero en éstas dos, es donde tengo algun error

Nota: dentro del código dejé los comentarios, Muchas gracias de antemano

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productos);

    request= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    listaProductos = new ArrayList<BDProductos>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.idReciclerProductos);

    String municipio=getIntent().getStringExtra("municipio");
    setTitle(municipio.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + municipio.substring(1));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Productos.this));
    //        Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tab.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          //Este método está definido en PageFragment, es lo que pretendo hacer
            PageFragment mostrarProductos=new PageFragment(listaProductos, getApplicationContext(), tab.getText(),  request,recyclerView);
            mostrarProductos.webServiceProductos();


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
    });


}
```

PageFragment.java

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener <JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener{
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    RecyclerView recyclerProductos;
    ArrayList<BDProductos> listaProductos;
    RequestQueue request;
    //news
    JsonObjectRequest jrq;
    Context context;
    CharSequence getN_negocio;
    ArrayList<BDProductos> listaProductosViejo;

   
public  PageFragment(){}
    public PageFragment(ArrayList<BDProductos> listaProductos, Context context,CharSequence getN_negocio, RequestQueue request,RecyclerView recyclerView){
        this.listaProductos=listaProductos;
        this.context=context;
        this.getN_negocio=getN_negocio;
        this.request=request;
        this.recyclerProductos=recyclerView;
    }


//CREA LAS PÁGINAS
    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);

        listaProductos = new ArrayList<BDProductos>();
        listaProductosViejo =new ArrayList<BDProductos>();
        recyclerProductos = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.idReciclerProductos);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        recyclerProductos.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerProductos.setHasFixedSize(true);
        request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    
        return view;
    }

// este es el método que utilizo para la base de datos y lo mando a llamar en la primera clase, porque es donde tengo los metodos OnClicks de los tabs

    public void webServiceProductos() {

        String tt= getN_negocio.toString();
        tt.replace(" ","%20");   String municipio="teste";
        String url= Servidor.hosting+"productos.php?accion=consultar&municipio="+municipio+"&nombre_negocio="+tt;
        jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jrq);

    }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        JSONArray jsonArray=response.optJSONArray("lista_productos");
        try {
            for (int i=0; i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                BDProductos productos=new BDProductos();
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                productos.setId_producto(jsonObject.optString("id_producto"));
                productos.setImagen(jsonObject.optString("imagen"));
                productos.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));
                productos.setPrecio(jsonObject.optString("precio"));
                productos.setDescripcion(jsonObject.optString("descripcion"));
                productos.setCategoria(jsonObject.optString("categoria"));
                productos.setTelefono(jsonObject.optString("telefono"));
                productos.setNombre_negocio(jsonObject.optString("nombre_negocio"));
                productos.setUbicacion(jsonObject.optString("ubicacion"));
                productos.setMunicipio(jsonObject.optString("municipio"));
                productos.setServicio_domicilio(jsonObject.optString("servicio_domicilio"));
                listaProductos.add(productos);
            }
            ProductosAdapter adapter= new ProductosAdapter(listaProductos,getContext());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

// Aquí es donde me marca error: recycler product = null. Todo el codigo funciona correctamente, ya hice pruebas, solo esta parte me sale null recyclerProducts

            recyclerProductos.setAdapter(adapter);
        }catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),error+"CHECAR AQUI",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Productos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PageFragment:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debug, todo funciona, menos la linea 166:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el error que se despliega en el LogCat podrías agregarlo exactamente como se muestra?

Comment: Lo acabo de agregar, gracias

Comment: Buenas, no entiendo el simplepageadapter, pero lo que quieres hacer yo lo hago de esta manera, son 3 fragments, 1 para cada tag, entonces cada fragment tiene su propio recyclerview, y hago fetch a la base de datos como cualquier activity se inicia en create view. Y todo funciona tranquilo.  El create view se ejecuta de las 3 al iniciar el activity, si quieres que sea cuando se scrollee el fetch a la base de datos tienes que usar algun listener del scroll o position y hacer fetch, (no te recomiento), varias app lo hacen asi como te digo, las 3 en 1 se fetchea a la base.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que revisar el layout `productos.xml` este debe contener el ViewPager con id `viewpager` del cual obtienes la referencia en esta línea:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

Si no existe, cuando trates de configurar el adapter con el método `setAdapter()` se provocará un `NullPointerException`

Comment: Hola Elenasys, sí existe, pero parece ser que el problema es de que no arranca  éste código en PageFragment que es donde tengo el recyclerview porque solo estoy llamando el método: `@Override  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { recyclerProductos = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.idReciclerProductos); LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        recyclerProductos.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerProductos.setHasFixedSize(true);    
        return view;
    }`

Comment: Estoy haciendo algo como esto, pero no me ha funcionado:            `Fragment frg = null;
            frg = fm.findFragmentByTag("refrescarFragmento");
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            ft.detach(frg);
            ft.attach(frg);
            ft.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no puedo comentar así que considere que esto es un comentario:

El problema parece ser en el `listaProductos = new ArrayList<BDProductos>()`, no almacena datos en los objetos por algún motivo y lo que pienso que es la clase `BDProductos` no tiene parámetros deberías ponerlo también para ponerlo en `listaProductos` en la función `onResponse`.

Otra observación es en la función `webServiceProductos()`, se cierra la llave antes de la función `onResponse` no debería estar dentro de la llave? Fíjate en las llaves creo que debería estar dentro de la función `onResponse` para funcionar la consulta.

Si no es entonces debes verificar una vez mas el ArrayList con los adaptadores que referencia con el RecyclerView dentro de la función indicado.

Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

El recyclerView esta null porque el mismo lo declaraste en el xml del fragmento (PageFragment).
Lo que tiene sentido porque es ahí donde se pinta. Lo que no te va a funcionar es cuando desde la actividad haces un findViewById(....) y lo pasas por el constructor del fragmento. No tiene sentido porque el RecyclerView no se encuentra en el xml de la actividad y desde la actividad no tienes acceso a los componentes de un fragmento con un findViewById(....)

Para que funcione has el mismo findviewById(...) pero en el fragmento (PageFragment), no lo pases por parametros en el constructor, porque ya lo tendrias propiamente en el fragmento. No pusiste los XML pero casi estoy seguro que es ahi donde lo tienes declarado. O al menos es ahi donde lo debes de declarar.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo Gustavo, de hecho así lo tenía como bién mencionas, sin embargo sale el mismo error y fué entonces que se me ocurrió pasarlo por parámetros desde la otra clase donde estoy llamando el método, porque pienso que el RecyclerView necesita actualizarse de alguna manera a la hora de dar click en la pestaña y lo que estoy haciendo es solamente ejecutar el método que está en PageFragment y no el onCreateView, entonces, como dices, busco alguna forma de llamar, ejecutar o pintar el recyclerView, talvez por eso me sale el error.

Comment: @Anselmo que tal si agregas los xml el del activity y el del fragment. Solo para tener visibilidad de como esta declarado los componentes, para ayudarte a dar una mejor respuesta

Comment: Listo, también subí una captura del debug, la consulta a la base de datos funciona muy bién y los guarda en BDProductos.java